# How to consume a message from a KStream output topic

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I am writing to output topic using KStream.to("outputtopic");
It was mentioned in apache documents that it will auto create the topic passed to the to(). How to consume message from that topic?

Can I use consumer.subscribe() to the outputtopic and poll messages?

```
        KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();

        builder.stream(topic).filterNot((k, v) -> {
            v.toString().contains(tid);
        }).to("outputtopic");

        streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, config);
        streams.start();

        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("outputtopic"));
```

Comment: If I understood correctly you need to continue consuming/processing the filtered output topic within your Stream app. In this case I guess you don't have to materialize the filtered stream to a topic. KStream.filterNot() returns new KStream, so you can just can continue working with it.

Comment: `It was mentioned in apache documents that it will auto create the topic passed to the to().` -- that does not sound correct -- it's your responsibility to create a topic that you use in `to()`. Can you point to the docs that mention this, so we can fix the docs?

Answer (score 1):

```java
builder.stream(topic).filterNot((k, v) -> {
            v.toString().contains(tid);
        }) // i.e., without the last `to()` method
```

The result of this chain of methods is a `KStream`. If your question is about how to continue operating on this resulting `KStream` *from within the same application*, then do sth like:

```java
KStream<..., ...> myStream = builder.stream(topic).filterNot((k, v) -> {
            v.toString().contains(tid);
        });
myStream.to("outputtopic");

// Then continue to use the `myStream` instance for further work.
myStream.map(....).aggregate(...);
```

If your question is about how to read the output topic from a *different application*, then you can do so by reading this topic from another Kafka Streams application, from KSQL, from a plain Kafka consumer (by subscribing), etc.

Comment: Thank you somuch. I don't want to read from different kafka client. So I will work with myStream